# Sorting eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, eigenvalue

The function `numpy.linalg.eig` supports calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a stack of matrices at once. In my case, I have 500000 2x2 matrices, organised in a 1000x500x2x2 numpy array, and calling `numpy.linalg.eig` on this returns 1000x500x2 eigenvalues and 1000x500x2 (2-component) eigenvectors. Just what I need. However, I need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to be sorted. I tried to sort the eigenvalues with

```
vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(array)
vals = vals[np.argsort(vals, axis = -1)]
```

yet this returns an array of shape 1000x500x2x500x2, instead of 1000x500x2, which I would expect. Is there a simple way to fix this, without resorting to looping over the array? And is there a similarly simple way to sort the eigenvectors according to the eigenvalues?

This question has sort of been answered here: [Sorted eigenvalues and eigenvectors on a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194671/sorted-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-on-a-grid) but the answer is tailored to a (another) special case, and not very well explained, and I haven't been successful in adapting it to my case. I considered posting a comment to that answer, asking for details, but I am currently at 49 reputation points, and you need 50 to comment.

Comment: Gave you an upvote, wish you luck with that comment :)

Comment: he needed a push :)

Comment: why don't you reshape your array to `500000x2x2`?

Comment: The reason I don't reshape prior to sorting is that it doesn't work. If I index a 500000x2 array with the result of argsorting that same array, it returns a 500000x2x2 array. The reason my array is 1000x500x2x2 in the first place is because it's more natural to express it that way. Basically, my goal is to obtain a vector field of 1000x500 vectors, made up by the eigenvectors associated with the smallest eigenvalue of the first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution developed in conjunction with [Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447207/tor). It will swap columns of the 2x2 matrices depending on "eigenvalue" order (fake eigenvectors generated by np.random).

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
Nx = 1000
Ny = 500
vals = np.random.rand(Nx, Ny, 2)
vecs = np.random.rand(Nx, Ny, 2, 2)
sort_order = np.argsort(vals, -1)
L = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(Nx), range(Ny), range(2))))
d0 = L[:,0]
d1 = L[:,1]
d2 = L[:,2]
vecsort = vecs[ np.c_[d0, d0], np.c_[d1, d1], np.c_[d2, d2], sort_order[d0, d1] ].reshape(Nx, Ny, 2, 2)
# vals can be sorted in place using:
vals.sort(axis=2)
```

Comment: That does indeed seem to do the trick. I can't say it's intuitively obvious how, though. Clearly I have to read up on the many interesting things found in `numpy.lib.index_tricks`. If you could explain how it works, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Sorry, but it turns out it doesn't actually work. This sorts the vector array along the next-to-last axis, but it should be the last axis. I should have been more clear in the question. From the documentation: "The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]."

Comment: Apologies, it's got me a bit stumped for now. I worked on your question as an exercise for myself - cannot claim to be a numpy guru :) My approach *might* work if you used `numpy.rot90` before and after sorting, but then it gets a bit messy.

Comment: I found a solution that works, by slightly modifying your code, using a separate L to sort the vectors: `L = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(Nx),range(Ny), range(2))))` and then `vecsort = vecs[ np.c_[L[:,0], L[:,0]], np.c_[L[:,1], L[:,1]], np.c_[L[:,2], L[:,2]], sort_order[L[:,0], L[:,1]] ].reshape(Nx,Ny,2,2)`, where `Nx = 1000` and `Ny = 500`. If you edit your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In the special case, that you have a **hermitian** or **real symmetric** matrix, you can use [eigh](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) from numpy. This returns the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in a sorted order, according to the current numpy reference manual!

For the general case, you can now use [take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis) to sort any array based on the index you obtained from `numpy.argsort` (see the [argsort manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)). This works directly for the eigenvalues. To sort the eigenvectors, you can use the same method, applied to each component of the eigenvectors separately. The following is an illustration. This approach is simple and not very fast, I guess, but I find it much easier to understand, compared to the previously sugested solutions. Maybe you can optimize it further.

```
import numpy as np

def eig_sorted(input_array):
   val, vec=np.linalg.eig(input_array)
   idx=val.argsort()
   val_sorted=np.take_along_axis(val, idx, -1)
   arr=[]
   for i in range(vec.shape[-2]):
      v=vec[...,i,:] #take one component
      arr.append(np.take_along_axis(v,idx,-1)) #sort it
   vec_sorted=np.stack(arr, -2) #stack everything together
   return val_sorted, vec_sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, however it just helped me implement something.
Therefore, I just wanted to add something (maybe trivial) on top of Tor's and Robert Davy's solution - how to generalize this for NxN matrices, where in their example N=2.

The solution is to copy N time the d-vectors, e.g. for N=3:

```
vecsort = vecs[ np.c_[d0, d0, d0], np.c_[d1, d1, d1], np.c_[d2, d2, d2], sort_order[d0, d1] ].reshape(Nx, Ny, 3, 3)
```